# Java game loop stutters

Tags: java, game-loop

As practice I tried to make a simple program where all you do is control the square around the screen. I`ve tried to make a game loop with interpolation however I am having issues with it, It often stutters and I dont know why. Ive tried removing Thread.sleep(1); to see if this is the issue. if I remove this it actually will decrease the stutter and the fps will jump from around 300 fps to around 8000 fps. But of course if I made this game more complex, I wouldnt be able to get 8000 fps so I wanted to see if the stuttering is still here if I only have around 300 fps so what I did is add a bunch of squares to the screen. This dropped the fps to around 300 and what I noticed is that the stuttering was back. Ive looked at [Game loop](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) and [Fix your timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) but I couldnt find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Game loop:

```
    int targetUps = 60;
    int timePerUpdate = 1_000_000_000 / targetUps;
    long oldTime = System.nanoTime();
    long newTime;
    int accumulator = 0;
    int upsTimer = 0;
    int upsCounter = 0;
    int fpsCounter = 0;

    while(true) {
        newTime = System.nanoTime();
        accumulator += newTime - oldTime;
        upsTimer += newTime - oldTime;
        oldTime = newTime;

        while(accumulator >= timePerUpdate) {
            update();
            accumulator -= timePerUpdate;
            upsCounter++;
        }

        render(Math.min(1.0f, (double) accumulator / timePerUpdate));
        fpsCounter++;

        if(upsTimer >= 1_000_000_000) {
            System.out.println("UPS: " + upsCounter + " | " + "FPS: " + fpsCounter);
            fpsCounter = 0;
            upsCounter = 0;
            upsTimer = 0;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

render method:

```
private void render(double delta) {
    BufferStrategy bs = window.getBufferStrategy();
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0,0,Window.WIDTH, Window.HEIGHT);
    player.render(g, delta);
    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}
```

Player`s render method:

```
 public void render(Graphics g, double delta) {
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    double renderX = oldX + (x - oldX) * delta;
    double renderY = oldY + (y - oldY) * delta;
    g.fillRect((int) renderX, (int) renderY, 32, 32);
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1)` is going to unconditionally sleep one second. You want the sleep time to depend on how much time is already spent. So for, say, 30 FPS, you'd want every frame to last ~33 nanoseconds. If the actual computation takes 16 nanoseconds, then you'd want to sleep 17 nanoseconds to make up the difference. This is called *delta timing*, and your code should be performing these calculations for you.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Right but if you are using interpolation that wouldn`t make sense because you want to render as fast as possible correct?

Comment: If you want to render "as fast as possible" then don't use `sleep` at all. You'll inconsistently get between 30 and 238742340174 FPS, depending on the OS' priorities, and you'll kill your processor's shelf life. You absolutely do *not* want to render as fast as possible. You want to aim for 30 or 60 FPS (studies have shown the average human eye can't process much better than 60 FPS) and forfeit the rest of the processing time to the OS for other software and tasks to run.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yeah I already removed Thread.sleep(); but that still doesn`t fix the stuttering.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1)` means sleep for 1 millisecond, not one full second, @SilvioMayolo

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delta like:

```
state = currentState * delta + previousState * ( 1.0 - delta );
```

When accumulator equals timePerUpdate (60 FPS) delta will be 0.

Since your code never uses (1.0 - delta),

```
 double renderX = oldX + (x - oldX) * delta;
 double renderY = oldY + (y - oldY) * delta;
```

means you're ignoring the update, and thus stutter.

Comment: You got a point. I tried this but now sometimes the square was jittering when stationary. I figured this was because when the square was at x 100.0 as example, sometimes x got calculated as 99.9 so it got rendered at x 99 instead. I tried to fix this by using Math.round() method to round both renderX and renderY and while it does fix jittering while stationary, it doesn`t fix the stuttering.